# Checkbox and radio button not saving selected option against multiple items in survey app in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, sql, laravel, survey, laravel-5.6

when I start adding answers in survey It is not saving answers on radio buttons and check boxes and only one question with checkbox or radio button on top of form is selected.

It saves only one question at a time or some times null or "on" keyword against checkbox or radio answers.Only first question with checkbox or radio button options can be selected.

When I try to selected other question's answer ,again only first question options are selected and only they are saving in db .kindly check the code and files and help me.

Only "on" keyword string is stored when I try to save checkbox or radiobutton options answer.If their is only one question with text the survey runs but in multiple it does not working with other questions

This is view of takesurvey.blade

```
 @forelse($survey->questions as $key=>$question)
          <p class="flow-text">Question {{$key+1}} - {{$question->title}}</p>
          @if($question->question_type==='text')
          <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="answer" type="text" name="{{$question->id}}[answer]">
                        <label for="answer">Answer </label>
                      </div>
                      @elseif($question->question_type==='textarea')
                      <div class="input-field col s12">
                      <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]"></textarea>
                      <label for="textarea1">Textarea</label>
                    </div>
                    @elseif($question->question_type==='radio')
                    @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)

                          <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                          <input name="{{$question->id}}[answer]" type="radio" id="{{ $key }}" />
                          <label for="{{$key}}">{{$value}}</label>
                          </p>
                          @endforeach
                          @elseif($question->question_type==='checkbox')
                          @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                          <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="something{{$key}}" name="{{$question->id}}[answer]"/>
                          <label for="something{{$key}}">{{$value}}</label>
                          </p>
                          @endforeach
                          @endif
                          <div class="divider" style="margin:10px 10px;"></div>
                          @empty
                <span class='flow-text center-align'>Nothing to show</span>
              @endforelse
              {{Form::submit('Submit Survey',array('class'=>'btn waves-effect waves-light'))}} 
              {!!Form::close()!!}
              </div>
      </div>
```

answercontroller

```
  public function store(Request $request,Survey $survey){
            $arr=$request->except('_token');
            foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
                $newAnswer=new Answer();
                if(!is_array($value)){
                    $newValue=$value['answer'];
                }
                else{
                    $newValue=json_encode($value['answer']);
                }
                $newAnswer->answer=$newValue;
                $newAnswer->question_id=$key;
                $newAnswer->user_id=Auth::id();
                $newAnswer->survey_id=$survey->id;
                $newAnswer->save();
                $answerArray=$newAnswer;
                return redirect()->action('SurveyController@view_survey_answers',[$survey->id]);
            }
```

Comment: You know checkboxes aren't sent in the post if they are not checked, right?

Comment: yes I know.The problem is that when I add more than one questions with checkbox or radio button in my survey,When i select checkbox or radio button for first question it is selected and saves "on" keyword in db not the actual value.whenever i try to select other question's checkbox or radio button they are not active.When I click on them,again It start selecting first or some times second question with checkbox or radio button option.Not that one which I want to select.And again It saves "on" keyword in database again first question's answer @Amarnasan